# Configurable android prefix

Tags: php, android

This application needs to have either a '#' or an '8' on different circumstances. This will be done through the PHP backend by passing the key called `room_to_room_prefix` i've created elsewhere.

This code swaps to a different fragment within the same activity when a button is pressed. When pressed, it swaps to a dialer and it is hardcoded to pass in a '#' sign in the textview. I'm wondering how I can make this a configurable prefix so that the backend can change it to either a '#' or '8' whenever they need.

```
room_call_lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EventTracker.getBuilder().action(TrackerConstant.ACTION_PHONE_BOOK_BUTTON_CLICK).value(TrackerConstant.EVENT_BUTTON_CLICK, "room to room call button").send();
            if (getContext() instanceof MainActivity) {
                ((MainActivity) getContext()).switchToDialFragment("#");
                TopToast.make(getContext(), getString(R.string.room_to_room_toast), TopToast.LENGTH_SHORT).setBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.themeColor)).show();
            }
        }
    });
```